# How to remove the rest of the line after a specific string

Tags: string, notepad++

So I am trying to remove the rest of the line after specific string on a document but I am finding it hard.

The lines look similar to this

```
abc:abc|bca:111 222|ccc:01/01/17
abc:abc|bca:bca bca|ccc:02/02/17
```

I am trying to delete everything after `abc:abc` including `|` but I don't know how.

I tried it with this on notepad+ `\|.bca*` but when I click Replace all it selects whole document.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `\|.*$`
- Replace with: `LEAVE EMPTY`
- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
- *DO NOT CHECK `. matches newline`*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
\|  : pipe character
.*  : 0 or more any character but newline
$   : end of line
```

**Result for given example:**

```
abc:abc
abc:abc
```